# Rails and Bundle for production with Passenger missing assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

We're having a small issue with our app. Currently we've made an update of the internal design and uploaded to the server, however running the following;

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

only precompiles certain items into the asset folder under public directory. Anyone else ran into the problem like this with suggestion how to fix. We have everything set correctly in environments and initializers.

Comment: what type of deploy are you guys leveraging? something like capistrano? A little more information would make this a lot easier to solve. Just more about your app and what not

Comment: no the guy that takes care of this told us to up it with FTP so that's what we did, we didn't use capistrano per his instructions. So direct, deploy was upload of the CSS files, and JS files using FTP

Comment: if I didn't mention, we're using passenger and nginx.

Comment: that guy does not sound like someone you should be listening to. I assume you guys messed up where updating the css files. Something like capistrano will take care of this for you. FTP seems like a horrible way to do this.

Comment: worked before when he did it however, any ideas why only the application.css is being cached? raking assets on our end seems to be fine also getting all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like some files are not getting into the precompile list. Try adding this to your config/application.rb

`config.assets.precompile = [/^[^_]/]`

This should be a catch all that will pick up all your js and css. Let me know if that works for you guys. Also you should be sure to tell that guy that you are listening to that deploying via FTP is silly.

Comment: yeah, we're going to be doing a proper Capistrano deployment tomorrow compare to his FTP version, from my experience in other development uploading CSS/JS files through FTP isn't bad at all, but I honestly did thing deployment of an app isn't the standard way of doing things. Thanks again, I'll let you know if all works.

Comment: ftp version is silly for so many reasons that a comment block cannot fit them all. An automated deploy is the way to go. I am going to assume you guys aren't using version control if you are using FTP deploys.

Comment: Marked this as the answer because it worked but only in situations where you have a bad deployment. If you do it right, no issue and no need for this fix, at least not for us anymore hiring someone else to do someone elses job. Thanks Dan for the tip.